# .net control monthcalendar grows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, monthcalendar

I am using the MonthCalendar control (version 4.0.0.0) in Visual Studio 2012 for a Windows Form application that is targeting the .NET 4.0 framework.  I cannot change the target framework do to the restriction that only the .NET 4.0 framework runs on the target machines.

On my development PC (Windows 7, .NET 4.5 framework, and VS2012) the control behaves the same in both Debug and Release.  The MonthCalendar has no anchors (as of now) but did have Top-Right, both experience the same issue of displaying too large (about 10 percent more) on the target boxes (Windows Server 2003).  The MonthCalendar is set to ShowToday = True and ShowTodayCircle = True from the properties box.

At runtime I set

`this.monthCalendar_SessionDates.SelectionStart =    this.monthCalendar_SessionDates.SelectionEnd = DateTime.Now;`

The only event used is DateSelected in which I update a listbox (on the same screen) the list of dates that the user selects so that they may see the different days they select.

Many sites suggest no anchors or setting the MaximumSize.  I have no anchors at this point and Maximum size is the same as Size.

Any additional suggestions or someone dealt with this before?

Comment: There's no option to control the size, it is determined by Windows.  Different versions of Windows have different calender look-and-feel.  It is used in a highly visible area, the clock on the taskbar, so it get tinkered with a lot from one version to another.

Comment: It turned out to be mostly due to the Font in properties.  I had changed it to 8 but when I checked again it was 12.  Not sure how it changed.  It went unnoticed as it did not change in font size in the development screen.  But there is still a difference in size but not as drastic.